# Are LGBT activists allowed to make gender education in Kindergartens in Germany?

Tags: education, gender, children, europe, lgbt

There are various rumors about this, particularly in the previous East Block. The goal of the activists is supposed to educate a more tolerant view for the children already in the early childhood. Opponents argument mostly by the (constitutional) rights of the parents to choose the education of their children. In the background, there is a kulturkampf between the liberalism and the traditional, mostly Christian values.

[Here](https://www-queer-de.translate.goog/detail.php?article_id=30596&_x_tr_sl=de&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=de&_x_tr_pto=wapp) I found a reference that the local government of Berlin actually financed this, but it is not clear, how extensive is this practice. There is also a [recent news](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2021/jun/15/hungary-passes-law-banning-lbgt-content-in-schools) about a new Hungarian law, essentially forbidding LGBT education until the elementary school.

Googling for that did not reveal too much for me, possibly I did not use the correct search keywords. Beside that, finding a trace by Google for something is much easier, than proving that it does not exist.

What is the reality?

Comment: "the (constitutional) rights of the parents to choose the education of their children" – I don't think that this is an appropriate summary of the legal situation in Germany as far as education is concerned. For instance, home-schooling is not possible in Germany, and schools need to be approved by the state. Crucially for this question, parents cannot decide what is being taught at schools – the curriculum is regulated on a state level. So if that's what the "opposition" is basing their argument on, they're going to lose the _kulturkampf_ on legal grounds.

Comment: After further consideration, I'm voting to close this question. It's too unfocused, and it's lacking a clear, falsifiable claim: Who claims that LGBT activists are allowed to educate in kindergardens in Germany? It's not in the link that you've posted – that's only about senate-issued information material  for kindergarden educators. So it's unclear what you mean when you say that the senate of Berlin "financed this" – financed what, exactly?

Comment: @Schmuddi Your first comment has a partial answer flavor, although I do not know this site customs. The first link I cited shows an example of a teach material paid by the local Berlin government. [This](https://www-die--tagespost-de.translate.goog/politik/lgbt-propaganda-in-katholischer-schule-eltern-wehren-sich-art-224772?_x_tr_sl=de&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=de&_x_tr_pto=wapp) is a case about "LGBT propaganda in a Catholic school – parents fight back".

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users). I have closed this because there is not a clear claim. The question seems to boil down to "Some people claim LGBT activity is immoral and children should not be exposed to any concepts as that will promote it. Others claim LGBT activity is perfectly fine, and children should be taught to be tolerant. Hence, there are disputes over education curricula." Do you doubt any of that? What is it you doubt?

Comment: @Oddthinking I think closing this question is not a solution. The Question seems to be motivated partly by a political view of the questioner. But the discussion could be fruitful. For example one could argue, that the German school system allows teachers sanctioned by churches, which are more or less homophobic. The even got special laws for their employees in germany.

Therefore the opposite is probably more true. And there there is no scientific evidence of the sexuality being influenced by how someone is educated. So even, if there is this agenda it will probably have no adverse effect.

Comment: The motivation behind the question is not in issue, we have no reason to suspect a bad actor here, but this is not a discussion site. We have a structured approach with clear requirements for how things are asked, clarity, focus, exact quotes that match the question, notability etc.. this question falls down on those, not integrity. We also don't engage in speculation, deductive or inductive logic unless supported by directly verifiable facts. @Darokthar That being said, balance of probability does enter into it from time to time, but only as a last resort (in answers as a rule).

Comment: @Darokthar: It wasn't closed because I agreed/disagreed with the political position of the OP. This isn't a political opinion discussion site. I closed it because there is no clear, notable claim which is required to be on-topic here. There is a link to a German pamphlet and a link to a proposed Hungarian law, but they don't appear to be relevant. There are mentions of rumours, but no cites.